# Serializing Class

Tags: java, serialization

I have a problem serializing:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SerializationSjow implements Serializable{

    public void serialization(Library library){
        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Test.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(library);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch(Exception i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public void deserialization(Library library){
        try{
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Test.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            library = (Library) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch(Exception i){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

it works fine if i put the same methods in before i call my mainMenu from my main class, but when i put them in a class and call them from my main method it wont serialize. (dezerialization first and then serialization after my mainMenu method is over).

main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Library library = new Library();
    SerializationSjow seri = new SerializationSjow();

    seri.deserialization(library);
    library.loginMenu();
    seri.serialization(library);
}
}
```

Comment: Show your main method. It is unclear what you doing and what error do you get.

Comment: The code you posted looks OK so that's not where the problem is.

Comment: i do the exact same thing in main method as this, its just that i want a clean main class so i moved the serialize to a class, and now it simply doesnt serialize, no errors, just doesnt save the arrays that i make.

Comment: so the serialize and deserialize doesnt lie in classes in the main, they just lie before and after the mainMenu() method is called.

Comment: ive uploaded my main class aswell. My fellow student is having the same problem in a different application, so he just decided to have them in the main class, but i would always prefer to just have method calls there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is **pass-by-value**! That means that variable passed to a method are passed by value and, and if the variable itself is changed in the method, this is not reflected outside the method.

Example:

```
private static void increment(int arg) {
    arg = arg + 1;
    System.out.println("incremented: " + arg);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 1;
    System.out.println("before: " + value);
    increment(value);
    System.out.println("after: " + value);
}
```

should print

> ```
> before: 1
> incremented: 2
> after: 1
> ```

In `main` we can see that the value has not changed...

Solution: change your `deserialization` method to return the `Library` instead of using a parameter:

```
public Library deserialization() { // no parameter
    Library library;
    :
    library = ...
    :
    return library;  // null on error? or better throw an Exception
}
```

Obs: there is no need for `SerializationSjow` to implement `Serializable` - it is not being serialized, it is `Library` that must implement it.

Comment: Ah makes sense! Thank you so much. Really explicit, just what i needed :)